# How to add a new variable to an existing group of settings in javascript

Tags: javascript

If I have a group of settings like so:

```
var settings = {
  showPostTags: true,
  showPostContent: true,
  showCategoryArchive: true,
}
```

and I wanted to add another setting(showPost) with 3 possible options(asRandom, asRecent, asRecentByLabel), to show certain parts of html, how would I write it?

This is what I tried:

```
var settings = {
  showPostTags: true,
  showPostContent: true,
  showCategoryArchive: true,
  showPosts: 'asRandom',
}

if (settings.showPosts('asRandom')) {
    HTML HERE
  }

if (settings.showPosts('asRecent')) {
    HTML HERE
  }

if (settings.showPosts('asRecentByLabel')) {
    HTML HERE
  }
```

Comment: You need to replace `settings.showPosts('asRandom')` with `settings.showPosts === 'asRandom'`. And I think you need to take another look at JavaScript docs/tutorials to get familiar with how the objects work.

Comment: Always check the error console...

Comment: you are trying to call a variable

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a variable as if it were an equality function.

You should use a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) in this scenario:

```js
var settings = {
  showPostTags: true,
  showPostContent: true,
  showCategoryArchive: true,
  showPosts: 'asRandom',
}

switch (settings.showPosts) {
  case 'asRandom':
    // HTML here
    break;
  case 'asRecent':
    // HTML here
    break;
  case 'asRecentByLabel':
    // HTML here
    break;
  default:
    // Else...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i would do:

```js
    // this can go in one file or constants object
    const DisplayOptions = {
      RANDOM: 1,
      MOST_RECENT: 2,
      BY_LABEL: 3
      // you can add more options in the future without breaking stuff
    }

    // example using the const
    var settings = {
      showPostTags: true,
      showPostContent: true,
      showCategoryArchive: true,
      showPosts: DisplayOptions.BY_LABEL
    }

    // example usage
    if (settings.showPosts === DisplayOptions.MOST_RECENT) {
        HTML HERE
    }
```

However, I would not set HTML here (unless it is something very simples like; less than 5 LOC...) as that will create a mess very quickly.

I would create a class per view type, on separate source files, then render that class according to the type passed.